# generate excel file as output in Java

Tags: java, excel

The following java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class extract
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String testData = new Scanner( new File("109.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        //String testData = "#1|77|1391436891|1|1|00:1e:58:f4:15:f7|Nexus 4, 4.4, MAKOZ30d $1|1391436893 ?[176.08179, -13.839829, -1.0054213] %PKKV7|00:7f:28:3f:17:9d|-67|2437 %DC2VJ|f8:e4:fb:a0:06:f8|-71|2412 %VVWSP|00:7f:28:d5:92:65|-71|2462 %SVT8H|f8:e4:fb:8e:d6:9b|-77|2437 %ThreeBestFriends|20:10:7a:14:6a:f7|-66|2452 %2X4C8|00:7f:28:44:23:da|-75|2437 %STDGD|f8:e4:fb:70:86:f4|-82|2462 %DeathStar|00:7f:28:be:c8:94|-84|2412 %Freeinternet|00:1e:58:f4:15:f7|-59|2437 %QB657|00:26:62:b7:16:4b|-88|2462 %375F2|00:26:b8:3e:0a:14|-70|2412 %E1K38|00:26:62:cf:90:37|-81|2412";
        String regularExpression = "\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}:\\w{2}\\W{1}-\\d{2}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testData);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }

    }
}
```

generates the following output:

```
00:1a:1e:87:04:42|-87
00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a2|-77
00:1a:1e:87:04:51|-95
00:1a:1e:84:92:02|-84
00:1a:1e:8d:f7:a2|-67
00:1a:1e:82:b8:e1|-56
00:1a:1e:82:b8:e2|-54
00:1a:1e:82:b8:e0|-56
00:1a:1e:87:04:41|-88
00:1a:1e:8d:f7:b1|-78
00:1a:1e:8d:f7:b2|-78
```

I'm trying to save output file as an excel file separated by columns.
Does anybody has any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add some commas (currently you don't have any), and save it as a text file named `some_file_name.csv`. You may use e.g. a [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) for this.

Saying 'Excel file separated by commas' is incorrect, actually the proper term is 'comma separated values file' or 'CSV file'. Programs other than Excel can open such files too.

Comment: If you need to make an xls file, you could use the POI library.